# Preventing X numbers from options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a script running to show a number in the select list options when the user check one specific value it will display a number refering to how much times he can pay his bill.

## Here is what it should be displayed:

1. If user select 1 box, he can do in 2x max, so it have to display the options 1x and 2x;
2. If user select 2 boxes, he can do in 3x max, so it have to display the options 1x, 2x and 3x;
3. If user select 3 boxes, he can do in 4x max, so it have to display the options 1x,2x,3x and 4x;
4. **If user select 4 boxes, he can do in 6x max, so it have to display the options 1x,2x,3x,4x AND 6x (5x should not appear);**
5. **5 boxes, 8x max (7x should not appear);**
6. **6 boxes, 10x max (9x should not appear);**
7. **7 boxes, 12x max (11x should not appear);**

## And here is the script code for this:

```
var tabelaParcelas = [];
tabelaParcelas[1] = 2;
tabelaParcelas[2] = 3;
tabelaParcelas[3] = 4;
tabelaParcelas[4] = 6;
tabelaParcelas[5] = 8;
tabelaParcelas[6] = 10;
tabelaParcelas[7] = 12;

$(document).ready(function(){
    update();
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    update();
})

    function update(){
        var amount2 = 0;
        var options = 0;
        $('#instNum2 option').remove();
        $('.check_list').each(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                amount2 += Number($(this).val());
                options ++;
            }
            $("input[name=amount]").val("R$"+amount2.toFixed(2));
    });

    if (options > 7) options = 7;
    var i = 0;
    if (options > 0) {
        while (tabelaParcelas[options] != i) {
            if (i != 0) {
            $('#instNum2')
            .append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value",i+1)
            .text((i+1)+"x"));
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

## HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Selecione</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Nome</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Situação</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Parcela</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Vencimento</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Valor Parcela</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Valor Devido</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Nome Responsável</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <?php
         foreach ($result as $value) {
            echo '<tr style="text-align: center;">
                    <td><input style="cursor: pointer;" type="checkbox" value="'. $value['VALORDEVIDO'] .'" class="check_list"></input>
                    <input style="display: none;" type="checkbox" checked="true" value="'. $value['CODIGOPARCELA'] .'" name="numControle"></td>
                     <td>'. utf8_encode($value['NOME']) .'</td>
                    <td>'. $value['SITUACAO'] .'</td>
                    <td>'. $value['PARCELA'] .'</td>
                    <td>'. $value['VENCIMENTO'] .'</td>
                    <td>'. $value['VALORPARCELA'] .'</td>
                    <td>'. $value['VALORDEVIDO'] .'</td>
                    <td>'. utf8_encode($value['NOMERESPONSAVEL']) .'</td>
                    </tr>';
        }

      ?>
   </tbody>
</table>

<select class="form-control" id="instNum2" name="instNum"></select>
```

> The problem is, the script keep showing 5x, 7x, 9x and 11x, and 1x is not even showing, I need to understand int the 1st place why the one that should'nt appear are showing up...

Could someone help me?

Comment: Could you please paste your html too so we can test?

Comment: @anpel , edited the question with html code!

Comment: $result is not defined here and the variable names are spanish so please help me understand what you are trying to achieve. My understanding is that if they select one row, they need to see only the option 2, if they select two rows, they need to see the options 2 and 3, they select 3, they see options 2,3 and 4. Is that correct or am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
var tabelaParcelas = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12];

$(document).ready(function() {
  update();
});

$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  update();
})

function update() {
  var list = $('#instNum2'); // use selector only once whenever possible for better performance

  // clear any existing options from the dropdown list
  list.html("")

  // count checked boxes, start from 1 to always include 1 option
  var checked_boxes = 1
  $(".check_list").each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      checked_boxes++;
    }
  });

  // append options to the select list
  for (var i = 0; i < checked_boxes; i++) {
    // break the loop to stop creating empty options
    if(i == tabelaParcelas.length){
        break;
    }
    var option = $("<option>", {
      value: tabelaParcelas[i],
      "text": tabelaParcelas[i]
    });
    list.append(option);
  }


}
```

Comment: That's correct bro! But the thing is, I need to display 1x as well, and that's what's not showing at all, 1x should be visible always no matter how much boxes you select, and other thing, when I select more than 7 boxes, the option keep producing empty options, while it should only keep displaying 12x without appending any new value